# Coffeescript not calling function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a function in JS. When I run it on the console I get the expected results

```
function hello(data) {
    $.foo = data;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://somesite.com/api?callback=hello&AssetId=123&returnFormat=json",
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

now when I convert it to coffee

```
hello = (data) ->
  $.foo = data
  return

$.ajax
  type: 'GET'
  url: 'http://somesite.com/api?callback=hello&AssetId=123&returnFormat=json'
  dataType: 'jsonp'
```

nothing happens

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: what are your expected results and what are you getting?

Comment: This is a correct translation for JS to CS. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: When I just load that on my page I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined(anonymous function) `